# CodeIgniter is caching view variable even if I explicitly set it again

Tags: php, caching, codeigniter

I'm using the CodeIgniter PHP framework. I have a simple form that has an $editcode hidden variable that gets sent on form submit. The form submits data to a form processing function which then redisplays the view with the form again, however with the $editcode$ variable changed to a new value.

The problem is that no matter what I do, the value of $editcode remains the same as the original value even after the form is submitted and the view redrawn with a new $editcode variable.

Extract from my view showing how $editcode is included and submitted.

```
echo form_open('/add', $formattributes);
echo form_hidden('editcode', set_value('editcode', $editcode));
echo form_submit('submit','Submit!','id="submit"');
```

The add() function code (the $refreshed_editcode is positively different from the original $editcode that got generated).

```
...
$data['editcode'] = $refreshed_editcode;
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
```

When the view gets redrawn by the add() function, the $editcode value *should* be $refreshed_editcode, but instead it's still the original value.

I know CodeIgniter does some caching of variables for nested views, however in this case I am explicitly resending new values for the $editcode variable. What gives?

Comment: Are you sure you are not manipulating `$editcode` in your view? May be some other is manipulating it. I would suggest doing a `print_r` or `var_dump`of `$data` in your view to check if the values are intact. This is a primitive way of debugging but helps :)

Comment: The only reference to $editcode in my view is the hidden form element. I did a print_r on $data before the view call and $editcode has the new correct value. However inside the view, the $editcode form element gets the same original value from before the form submit!

Comment: may b am shooting in the dark, but by any chance are you using registered globals on? or in any step you are converting `$_POST` keys to their respective var names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the call to set_value. Since the form field is hidden, it really shouldn't give you much benefit anyway, and I suspect that is where the "caching" is happening (If I'm not mistaken that function is part of the form_helpers file and it actually is designed to cache to help re-populate data, but it has been a while since I've used it).

Comment: You were spot on! I removed the reference to set_value and instead put in an <input type="hidden"> tag and that did the trick. Thanks!